# JS/jQuery: how many character occurance in textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

Assuming:
str value = 'This is some text';

I want to count how many 't' occurrences, how to do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is much easier with regex

```
var regex = new RegExp("t", "gi")
var count = "This is some text".match(regex).length;
```

Will give you counts of `t` in the given string(ignore case).

You can test it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/WB7jD/).

Further reference
[RegExp 1](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp)
[RegExp 2](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html)
[String](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_string.asp)
[String.match()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp)

Answer (score 4):

```
var sValue = 'This is some text';
var tCount = sValue.split("t").length - 1;
alert("t appears " + tCount + " times");
```

If you want to count occurrences of all letters, you better use one loop as shown in the other answers.

Comment: This is fine so long as you don't switch to using a regex for the `split()`, where you would start to have problems in IE with two adjacent matches.

Comment: @Tim yep, this one is "non regex" solution, using regex there's no point in split anyway. :)

Answer (score 2):

An easy solution is to loop

```
var count = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i ++) {
  if(str.charAt(i) === 't')
    ++count;
}
```

You might also want to use `str.toLowerCase();` if you don't want to be case sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

I think you all make it more complicated than it needs to be. Use regex. This is also case insensitive. If you want case sensitive, remove the i after g.

```
var str = "This is some text";
var pattern = /t/gi;
alert(str.match(pattern).length);
```

Make it shorter.

```
var str = "This is some text";
alert(str.match(/t/gi).length);
```

Comment: Regex is actually pretty expensive so the solution to use split is probably the fastest solution suggested

Answer (score 0):

Several ways to do this...

```
function countChar(str, searchChar) {
   var num=0;
   for (var i=0; i<str.length; ++i) {
      if (str[i] == searchChar)
         ++num;
   }
   return num;
}
```

use like:

numt = countChar('This is some text', 't');

Answer (score 0):

```
<button onclick="alert(countCharacter('abcdea', 'a'));"> Test! </button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function countCharacter(sample, characterToFind) {
        var result = 0;

        for(i = 0;i<sample.length;i++) {
            if(sample[i] === characterToFind) {
                result++;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

May be can help you here

```
.replace().length
```

with regards

**Wazzy**