# how to find that how many times a specific word is written in one textarea using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea

First of all, I am NOT good at javascript or jquery, so I thought to search in the internet first, like I always do for things that I do not know. But I could not find anything about my question, so I thought to ask for help here and I hope you can help me.

When I started to ask the question, this website told me to share my research, but I do not have what to share.

My question is: "How to find that how many times a specific word is written in one textarea using javascript or jquery?"

I am not sure if that can be done with javascript or jquery, that's why I wrote both those.

Thanks

Comment: You need to use a regular expression. Here is a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4594074/js-jquery-how-many-character-occurance-in-textarea).

Comment: Are you searching for specific words (the count of, for example, the word 'apple,' and would that be distinct from 'Apple'), or simply a count of *every* word used in the input/textarea?

Comment: for specific words, for example the word "img". I would like to know how many times that word is written in a textarea.

Comment: @epascarello i have a html textarea. how can that example help me?

<textarea name="komenti" id="komenti" cols=50 rows="7" required></textarea>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple proof-of-concept:

```
$('#test').keyup(function(e){
    var v = $(this).val(), // the current value of the textarea,
        w = v.split(/\s/), // the individual words
        needle = 'img', // what you're looking for
        c = 0; // the count of that particular word
    for (var i=0,len=w.length;i<len;i++){
        // iterating over every word
        if (w[i] === needle){
        // if a given word is equal to the word you're looking for
        // increase the count variable by 1
            c++;
        }
    }
    // set the text of the 'output' element to be the count of occurrences
    $('#output').text(c);
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Jdk4f/).

References:

- [`keyup()`](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/).
- [`String.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).
- [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).
- [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

Comment: If you really want to split on words, you should use word boundaries instead of spaces.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) to match regular expressions in a string.

```
var str = "This my wordy string of words";
console.log(str.match(/word/g).length); // Prints 2 as it's matched wordy and words
console.log(str.match(/word\b/g).length); // Prints 0 as it has NOT matched wordy and words due to the word boundary
```

These are also case sensitive. You may want to study up [RegExp's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) for additional options.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
var regex = new RegExp('\\b' + word + '\\b', 'gi');
var count = string.match(regex).length
```